# Any way to save the State and data of PagedListView?

Tags: flutter, pagination

I wanted to ask if it's possible to save the state and data (which is already loaded) in a PagedListView( from infinite_scroll_pagination), because every time I change the to another View the state and data is lost.
I am using a PageView to navigate between different Views.

I already tried PageStorage but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try `automaticKeepAlives` to true to keep the state of your widgets. You can also manage the keep_alive thing inside a single item.

```
PagedListView(
        pagingController: _pagingController,
        addAutomaticKeepAlives: true,
        ..............
        ...............
      );
```

Comment: The default value of the addAutomaticKeepAlives field is true so you don't have to set it and it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I used an IndexedStack instead of a PageView.